# How to implement AND logic in native Shopify filter?

Tags: filter, shopify, storefront

I using a native storefront filter by products tag in Shopify.
`shop_url/collection/collection_name?filter.p.tag=gold,diamond`.
But as result, I get products made of gold and products containing diamond (not only of gold).
Therefore, I need the filter to work according to the logic AND and not OR.
I tried use `shop_url/collection/collection_name?filter.p.tag=gold+diamond` and `shop_url/collection/collection_name?filter.p.tag=gold&filter.p.tag=diamond` but its didnt work.

As a result, I only want to get gold products that contain a diamond.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use tags for filtering then you can use tag filtering instead of storefront filtering.

Like this:

shop_url/collection/collection_name/gold,diamond